# How to implement next button in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am using `jspaginator` from github to show 10 notices at a time and 5 per page on a.But I doesn't provide any NEXT button to fetch more results on user request.So I want to implement it on my own .I had following PHP code -

```
                $start=0;
                $end=10;
                $query='select * from notice order by id desc limit '.$start.','.$end.';';
                if($query_run=mysql_query($query))
                {
                  $query_num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query_run);
                if($query_num_rows==0)
                  {
                    echo '<h4>No Notices</h4>';
                  }else {
                    echo    '<div id="green-contents" class="contents" ">
                              <table id="mt" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table">
                              <tr class="header">
                              <th>
                                Date Posted
                              </th>
                              <th width="55%">
                               title
                              </th>
                              <th>
                               Posted By
                              </th>
                              <th>
                                Branch
                              </th>
                                 <th>
                                Semester
                              </th>
                              </tr>';
                    for($i=0;$i<$query_num_rows;$i++)
                    {
                        echo '<tr>
                                 <td>'.mysql_result($query_run,$i,'posted_on').'</td>
                                 <td class="note"><h4><a href="view_notice.php?id='.
                                 mysql_result($query_run,$i,'id').'">';
                                 if(strlen(mysql_result($query_run,$i,'title'))>48)
                                    echo (substr(mysql_result($query_run,$i,'title'),0,45)).'.....';
                                  else
                                    echo mysql_result($query_run,$i,'title');
                        echo      '<td>'.mysql_result($query_run,$i,'posted_by').'</td>
                                 <td>'.mysql_result($query_run,$i,'branch').'</td>
                                 <td>'.mysql_result($query_run,$i,'semester').'</td>';
                    }
                    echo '</table>';
                  }
                }else
                echo mysql_error();
```

Now ,how can I change the `$start` and `$end` and execute the query again to fetch next 10 results.

Comment: Look up `php pagination`, there are many good tutorials

Comment: @Pekka:I am using `jspaginator` from github but it does not have any option to fetch next results so I want to implement it on my own

Comment: @Insane, can you add details about that to your question, by editing it? That sounds relevant, and without it, people will offer the same advice as Pekka.

Comment: Only 1239403202 results for this.. http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/phpTutorial/mysqlPagingResults.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your `start` parameter dynamic. So that could be via a `$_GET` parameter with URLs like **http://example.com/filename.php?page=1**.

Your script would look like this:

```
<?php

$batch = 10;
$page = (intval($_GET['page']) > 0) ? $_GET['page'] : 1; // set $page if it's a number greater than zero

$start = (($page - 1) * $batch);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT :offset, :limit";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':offset', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':limit', $batch, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

You’ll notice I’ve not used `mysql_` functions in the above code snippet. The reason is two-fold:

1. The `mysql_` family of functions are deprecated and should not be used, instead alternatives such as [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) should be used.
2. PDO allows creating statements, where data is denoted by tokens (`:limit`). This is to avoid just using variables inline in your SQL statements and to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks Martin , I will stick to your `mysql_` advice in future.And thanks it solved my problem.

Comment: No problem. Glad you sorted it!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a hidden input in your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="'.$_GET['page']+1.'>
```

then an if at your $start, $end vars

```
if (isset($_GET['page']))
{
 $start = $_GET['page'];
 $end = $_GET['page']+9;
}
else
{
 $start = 0;
 $end = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass next page value in url like this `notices.php?page=2` and use blow code for `$start` value

```
$page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? intval($_GET["page"]) : 1;
if (0 == $page) {
    $page = 1;
}

$start = 10 * ($page - 1);
$end = 10;
```